# What tense should I use in this paraphrasing sentence?

Tags: tenses, writing

This is a question from an IELTS Essay.

- *Although more and more people read news on the Internet, newspapers will remain the most important
  source of news for the majority of people.*

We are required to paraphrase the topic. I'm not sure about the tense that should be used when I paraphrase this sentence.

My paraphrase would be:

- *Nowadays, despite the rising trend of readers prefer to read news online, it is thought that the overarching source of information "is still deriving from newspapers"  for most people.*

I wonder what tense should I use for the verb tense since the original text is a simple future (will remain).

1. is still deriving from newspapers
2. will still be deriving from newspapers
3. or is there any better alternative?

Comment: This is a forecast, so a future timeframe is needed. '... most people will still get/acquire most of their news by reading newspapers.' (The suggested paraphrase is high-flown and ungrammatical.)

Answer (score -1):

Better to use the simple present tense because it is with what the first sentence begins with the word Nowadays and then connects simple future.
Despite the ease of accessibility and availability of the internet these days, the existence of newspapers can never be neglected as a majority of people are still inclined towards reading newspapers.

Comment: Thank you! your paraphrase is great. i didnt think of that! 

so, I'd like to confirm with you that you use "can" in the form of a simple present tense because it started with Nowadays?

What if the sentence doesn't start with nowadays, would you still use present simple?

Comment: Nowadays represents the present tense. I wouldn't be using the present tense if nowadays is not there. Feel free to ask your doubts regarding paraphrasing.

Comment: The paraphrase loses 'newspapers will remain **the most important** source of news for the majority of people and has other issues.